# Equalize height of Div-Columns in YAML

Tags: html, css, yaml-css

I'm trying to create a three columns layout in YAML. I'm using the grid feature of this framework to position the columns (navigation, content, sidebar).

My Question: how can I set the height of all three divs to the same size. YAML should offer the `ym-equalize` class but it seems that this isn't working the proper way or I'm doing it wrong.

You can find the source code (without the framework) here: https://gist.github.com/3fb9187c92eefa7ef731

Edit: I know there is a javascript and/or position: absolute solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by RTF(German YAML Forum) and googleing. Just add this to ym-grid container

```
ym-equalize grid-equalheights
```

I've added this to my problem in gist, see here for fixed version: https://gist.github.com/3fb9187c92eefa7ef731